# byobu-tmux seems to have a memory leak, how can I find it?

Tags: byobu, tmux

As you can see this instance has been running for 5+weeks and is now using nearly 1GB of memory.

```
$ ps auxww | grep tmux
jrwren    9839  6.0 11.7 969508 943140 ?       Ss   Jun27 3201:33 tmux -u -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
```

How can I find what is causing tmux to leak memory? I assume it is a byobu config option causing the leak because if I run tmux outside of byobu it does not leak memory like this.